# Notation confusion for joint pdf expected value

Tags: probability, notation

I have a pdf for continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$

such that $f_{xy}(x,y) = 2(x+y)$ for all $0<x<y<1$ and $0$ elsewhere

I'm not sure how to break up the inequality to determine my limits of integration to find the expected value.

Does this mean for $0<x<1$ and $ 0<y<1$ or $0<x<y$ and $x<y<1$?

I have to find $E[X^2Y]$

Following the latter definition, $0<x<y$ and $x<y<1$, I have an expected value in terms of $x$ which doesn't seem correct.
My limits of integration were $(0,Y)$ for dx(inner integral) and $(x,1)$ for dy(outer integral)

Comment: Draw the triangle on which the joint density lives. The picture makes it clear that  $x$ will go from $0$ to $y$, and then $y$ will travel from $0$ to $1$. Alternately, but slightly messier, $y$ goes from $x$ to $1$ and then $x$ goes from $0$ to $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:
$$
\mathbb{E}X^2Y=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{y}x^2yf_{XY}(x,y)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=
$$
$$
=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{y}2x^2y(x+y)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{7 y^5}{6}\mathrm{d}y=\frac{7}{36}
$$

---

### [image]

An image of the pdf, it is only defined to be different from $0$ in the blue region.

Comment: Do you have to make sure y is greater than x? How did you interpret the inequality 0<x<y<1 in picking limits of integration of the outer integral?

Comment: Yes, because the support of the  pdf is defined to be  $$\text{supp}f_{XY}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|0<x<y<1\} $$